# Combining and formatting lists in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I've got a list of point pairs (in NetLogo coordinates) called "coords" that looks like this:

```
[[[255 97] [256 97]] 
 [[-131 408] [-129 407]]
 [[-125 406] [-122 405]] 
 [[-84 188]] [-83 188]]
 [[-303 200] [-304 203]]
 [[25 414] [19 415]]
 [[-128 256] [-125 254]]
 .......................................]
```

Each point pair has associated with it a classification variable, which takes one of the values "I", "U", or "S".  I have a separate list of these classification variables, called "coord_class" the same length and in the same order as the point pairs listed above.

```
["S" "S" "U" "I" "S" "I" "U" ...]
```

What I would like to do is append the corresponding classification variable to the point pairs, in a way that looks like this:

```
[[[255 97 "S"] [256 97 "S"]] 
 [[-131 408 "S"] [-129 407 "S"]]
 [[-125 406 "U"] [-122 405 "U"]] 
 [[-84 188 "I"]] [-83 188 "I"]]
 [[-303 200 "S"] [-304 203 "S"]]
 [[25 414 "I"] [19 415 "I"]]
 [[-128 256 "U"] [-125 254"U"]]
 .......................................]
```

Note that both points in a given pair take the same classification variable value.

I've attempted to do this using the map reporter:

```
set coords (map [list ?1 ?2] coords coord_class)
```

which gives an output that looks like this:

```
[[[[255 97] [256 97]] "S"] 
 [[[-131 408] [-129 407]] "S"]
 [[[-125 406] [-122 405]] "U"] 
 [[[-84 188]] [-83 188]] "I"]
 [[[-303 200] [-304 203]] "S"]
 [[[25 414] [19 415]] "I"]
 [[[-128 256] [-125 254]] "U"]
 .......................................]
```

This isn't structured properly for other functions in the code.  Any advice to help me obtain the desired output would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of lists of lists. Doing what you want will require two separate `map` operations. The easiest way to do this is probably to split the task between two small reporters:

```
to-report add-classes [ coords classes ]
  report (map add-class coords classes)  
end

to-report add-class [ lists class ]
  report map [ lput class ? ] lists
end
```

You can then use it like this:

```
to go
  let coords [
    [ [ 255  97] [ 256  97] ]
    [ [-131 408] [-129 407] ]
    [ [-125 406] [-122 405] ]
    [ [ -84 188] [ -83 188] ]
    [ [-303 200] [-304 203] ]
    [ [  25 414] [  19 415] ]
    [ [-128 256] [-125 254] ]
  ]
  let coord_class ["S" "S" "U" "I" "S" "I" "U"]
  show add-classes coords coord_class
end
```

Which will print the desired output:

```
[[[255 97 "S"] [256 97 "S"]] [[-131 408 "S"] [-129 407 "S"]] [[-125 406 "U"] [-122 405 "U"]] [[-84 188 "I"] [-83 188 "I"]] [[-303 200 "S"] [-304 203 "S"]] [[25 414 "I"] [19 415 "I"]] [[-128 256 "U"] [-125 254 "U"]]]
```

Comment: Great, this worked perfectly.  Hypothetically speaking, if I wanted to concatenate another set of attributes would I just nest the second block of code.  For example: set combined-classes add-classes coords coord_class

set ultra-combined-classes add-classes combined-classes new-field

Comment: That works, yes. But it's actually a pretty good use case for [`reduce`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce). Try: `show reduce add-classes (list coords coord_class new-field)`. (And you can add as many fields as you want to the list.)